# How to move an image on top of other image in tkinter canvas?

Tags: python, tkinter, image-processing, drag-and-drop, tk-toolkit

I'm trying to make an app similar to photoshop using tkinter. I've used tkinter's list box to implement image layering functionality just like in photoshop where each item in the list box corresponds to an imported image. When one item in the list box is dragged on top of the other or under, the corresponding image should also be placed on top or underneath the other image. How can I  implement this without having to recreate the image as the positioning of the items in the list box change. I tried using item config method but it didn't work

[image: here is the image of my app]

and here is the code (its not the whole code only the relevant functions) (Also ignore indents and formatting)

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import filedialog
import shutil as shu
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
import os


#importing the image into listbox and canvas

   def open(self): #importing the image and inserting into listbox
        file=filedialog.askopenfilename()
        self.temp.append(file)
        for i in self.temp:
            shu.copy(i, 'cache/') #copying the files in a folder called cache
        layers=os.listdir('cache/')

        for i in layers:
            if i not in self.layerbox.get(0,END): #self.layerbox is the listbox
                self.layerbox.insert(0,i)
        self.temp=[]
        self.layer_naming+=1
        self.drawoncanvas()
        os.chdir(self.parent_path)

        def drawoncanvas(self):# this function reads the listbox and displays the images accordingly
         os.chdir('cache/')
    for index,i in enumerate(reversed(self.layerbox.get(0,END))):
        if i not in self.laycanconnect:
            exec('self.pic'+str(index)+'=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(i))')
            exec('self.pix'+str(index)+'='+ 'self.canvas.create_image(self.canvas.winfo_width()/2,self.canvas.winfo_height()/2,image=self.pic'+str(index)+')')
            exec('self.connector(i,self.pic'+str(index)+')') #There are two  empty dictionaries to store the image creation variable i.e self.pix and the image ii.e self.pic
            exec('self.connector2(i,self.pix'+str(index)+')')
            # self.connector and self.connector2 functions references both image and canvas creation variable using the image file name





    def connector(self,name,key):
        self.laycanconnect[name]=key   #self.laycanconnect and self.laycanconnect2 are the two dictionaries
    def connector2(self,name,key):
        self.laycanconnect2[name]=key


    def setcurrent(self,event):                            #These two functions are bound by mouse events Button 1 and B1-Motion 
                                                            #inorder to implement dragging and dropping of listbox items
        self.curindex=self.layerbox.nearest(event.y)
    def shift(self,event):
        global corx,cory
        i=self.layerbox.nearest(event.y)
        y = self.layerbox.get(self.curindex)
        corx, cory = self.canvas.coords(self.laycanconnect2[y])
        if i<self.curindex: #moving up
            x=self.layerbox.get(i)
            self.layerbox.delete(i)
            self.layerbox.insert(i+1,x)
            self.curindex = i
        elif i>self.curindex:#moving down
            x=self.layerbox.get(i)
            corx, cory = self.canvas.coords(self.laycanconnect2[x])
            self.layerbox.delete(i)
            self.layerbox.insert(i-1,x)
            self.curindex=i
        for  i in reversed(self.layerbox.get(0,END)):
            self.canvas.delete(self.laycanconnect2[i])
            self.laycanconnect2[i]=self.canvas.create_image(corx,cory,image=self.laycanconnect[i])
            #Here is the problem I don't want to recreate the image in order to place 
            #an image over the other
```

Comment: Try `self.canvas.tag_raise(self.laycanconnect2[i])`.

Comment: You should be able to do this, but are going to need to provide a [mre] (MRE).